# Diode sine wave shaper - location of break points

Tags: diodes, math, waveform, sine

I'm attempting to generate a sine wave from a triangular wave using the diode breakpoint method where the sine wave is approximated by multiple straight-line segments. Where should the breakpoints be located in order to produce the cleanest (lowest THD) sine wave, all else being equal.

[image]

For instance, in the above image where 4 line segments are used, where should x1, x2, and x3 be located in order to produce an optimal sine wave? What if an arbitrary number of line segments are used? I'm planning on using 7 in my circuit.

I've attempted to formulate an error function from the difference between the area under the sine curve and the area under the straight-line segments, then minimize this error function. However, this appears to lead to an optimization problem in many variables, and doing this by hand looks frightening. This looks like something that Excel or Octave could do fairly easily, but I don't have much experience in this area. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check [TI's AN-263 Sine Wave Generation Techniques, chapter 9](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa665c/snoa665c.pdf)

Comment: Approximating a sine with line segments rather is a *mathematical* question than an *electronical* question.

Comment: Diodes don't clip hard, they clip soft, the problem is more difficult to solve than you believe.

Comment: If you use the circuit in Huisman's comment. And, the diode I-V relationship in this link: https://2n3904blog.com/1n4148-diode-forward-biased-i-v-curve/  which concluded that:  log(Id) = 20.6Vd - 19.8 (for one 1N4148 sample, it varied), you can derive the equations. Unfortunately, they are difficult to solve.